# Mapbox-GL Labels Layer Non-Transparent

Tags: javascript, background, transparency, label, mapbox-gl-js

I would really appreciate a hint on using Mapbox-GL map styles containing default labels(like `"mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v9"` or `"mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"`)

I have not seen any issues with these map styles in modern browsers on a desktop. However, on **some** mobile devices, a Mapbox-GL map is displayed only if the style contains no labels (e.g. `"mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9"`). Otherwise, a map is displayed for less than a second, and then the labels layer (which appears to be non-transparent) is added making the map not visible any more. Here is an example: https://secure194.inmotionhosting.com/~evnica5/fh-projects/CycleJoy/mapWithLabels.html. This is a pure copy of the Mapbox-GL example from here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/. The only difference is that the map style is replaced with the one containing labels.

Have you seen this behaviour in your projects? Are there any workarounds, such as manually setting the transparency of the labels layer? Or maybe I am digging in the wrong place and the issue has nothing to do with the transparency at all?

Thanks a lot and have a great day!

Comment: If it sounds like a bug, probably better to raise it on the Issues: http://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Steve